# Передача атрибута класса другому классу

Tags: python

```
class Admin(User):
def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, city):
    super().__init__(first_name, last_name, age, city)
    self.privileges = Privileges()
```

```
class Privileges(Admin):
    def __init__(self,):
        self.privileges = ['dsqdqd', 'sdqfq', 'dqwfqwf', 'dqwffqwf']

    def show_privileges(self):
        for privilege in self.privileges:
            print(privilege)
```

Вопрос: как передать функцию show_privileges в класс Админ?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под передачей функции?

Comment: У объекта класса `Admin` вызовите `.privileges.show_privileges()`, типа: `admin = Admin()` `admin.privileges.show_privileges()`

Comment: А зачем вы наследуете `Privileges` от `Admin` вообще?

Comment: @gi9red спасибо за помощь